# PyInstaller maximum recursion error after pre-safe import module hook [six.moves]

Tags: python, exe, python-3.5, pyinstaller, six

I am trying to use PyInstaller to convert my python3.5 project into an .exe file
My main file is SegTool.py

This is my .spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['SegTool.py'],
              pathex=['consts.py', 'FetalMRI_about.py', 'FetalMRI_mainwindow.py', 'FetalMRI_workspace.py', 'image_label.py', 'main_window.py', 'scan_file.py', 'segment3d_itk.py', 'Shapes.py', 'workspace.py', 'C:\\Users\\Keren Meron\\Documents\\School Work\\Fetal MRI\\FetalSegBrainTool'],
            binaries=[],
            datas=[('images', 'images')],
            hiddenimports=[],
            hookspath=[],
            runtime_hooks=[],
            excludes=[],
            win_n_no_prefer_redirects=False,
            win_private_assemblies=False,
            cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='SegTool',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=False,
           upx=True,
           name='SegTool')
```

Maybe I don't understand enough the hooks and dependencies related, but I am getting a crash:

```
File "C:\Users\Keren Meron\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\ast.py", line 245, in visit
    return visitor(node)
File "C:\Users\Keren Meron\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\ast.py", line 253, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
File "C:\Users\Keren Meron\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\ast.py", line 245, in visit
    return visitor(node)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The output (DEBUG and INFO are on) right before the traceback:

`10923 INFO: Caching module hooks...
10937 INFO: Analyzing SegTool.py
13458 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
14204 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
14205 DEBUG: win32com: extending __path__ with dir 'C:\\Users\\Keren Meron\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\\python-3.5.3.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\win32comext'
14604 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
16281 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
16284 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\Keren Meron\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\\python-3.5.3.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
40968 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   requests.packages.urllib3.packages.six.moves
51591 DEBUG: load_module: SyntaxError in  'C:\\Users\\Keren Meron\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\\python-3.5.3.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2\\asyncsupport.py'`

Please help, what do I need to do to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This might be too late, but I faced this issue too, and fixed it by adding a couple of lines of code in the spec file at the top:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

block_cipher = None
```

Hopefully, this fixes you issue too, if it is still open!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to upgrade setuptools using the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing a problem with PyInstaller installation or you want to update to the latest version, it is recommended to use the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade pyinstaller
```

If it does not work, Try the following command to force reinstall!

```
pip install --force-reinstall --no-binary :all: pyinstaller
```

Comment: Or update to newer version of pyinstaller: `pip install -U pyinstaller`. Currently, `pyinstaller==4.10` works for me.