# PyInstaller not working Windows. Hooks error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Having issues running pyinstaller on a little script&gui I made.
Works fine when run as a script.
I am not really sure what else to try and don't understand the nature of hooks.
If there isn't an easy solution is there a workaround I could try?

**Here's the dependencies in the code:**

```
import os 
import shutil
import sys
import math
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.oxml.table import CT_Tbl
from docx.oxml.text.paragraph import CT_P
from docx.table import Table
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import traceback
```

**Here's what happens when I try to run pyinstaller:**

```
(base) C:\Users\cnelson>pyinstaller --onefile -w C:\Users\cnelson\.spyder-py3\CSandSOWCreationRev001.py
2154 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.2
2154 INFO: Python: 3.8.5 (conda)
2155 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
2157 INFO: wrote C:\Users\cnelson\CSandSOWCreationRev001.spec
2163 INFO: UPX is not available.
2165 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\cnelson\\.spyder-py3', 'C:\\Users\\cnelson']
2300 INFO: checking Analysis
2300 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
2301 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
2321 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
2350 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'win32ctypes.core'. Please take care they do not conflict.
2374 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
11386 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\cnelson\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
11391 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\cnelson\\anaconda3\\lib'
18206 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
18374 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
18398 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\cnelson\anaconda3\python.exe
18780 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\cnelson\.spyder-py3\CSandSOWCreationRev001.py
24790 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'c:\\users\\cnelson\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
24794 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\cnelson\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
28539 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook setuptools.extern.six.moves from 'c:\\users\\cnelson\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cnelson\.spyder-py3\setuptools\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "C:\Users\cnelson\.spyder-py3\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Users\cnelson\.spyder-py3\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    from pkg_resources.extern import appdirs
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\cnelson\.spyder-py3\pkg_resources\extern\__init__.py", line 43, in load_module
    __import__(extant)
  File "C:\Users\cnelson\.spyder-py3\pkg_resources\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 560, in <module>
    import win32com.shell
  File "C:\Users\cnelson\.spyder-py3\win32com\__init__.py", line 93, in <module>
    __gen_path__ = iter(sys.modules["win32com.gen_py"].__path__).next()
AttributeError: 'list_iterator' object has no attribute 'next'
pre-safe-import-module hook failed, needs fixing.
```

Comment: Try reinstalling Pyinstaller with pip explained here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3777
Or upgrade setuptools like explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076325/pyinstaller-maximum-recursion-error-after-pre-safe-import-module-hook-six-moves

Comment: Tried both of these (had previously found the former post and re-tried it just now) to no avail.

Comment: Try to create the pyinstaller exe with a command window in the background - it might give you more of a hint of the specific problem

Comment: @qwerty12 like open a second cmd terminal beside the one running pyinstaller?

Comment: if so, nothing happened in the second window

Comment: yes so running `pyinstaller -y -F "myscript.py"` when compiling

Comment: @qwerty12 this did not appear to do anything/ nothing happens in the second cmd prompt or when running pyinstaller -y -F "myscript.py".  i am not sure what I should be expecting in the second terminal or how it is being expected to interface with the other script. Any chance you could point me to a resource to understand what/how to try and get more information using this?

Comment: Sometimes the cmd shows a more specific error.  Ive had some issues with these libraries before. Have you pip installed them or conda forge? Also look into these sites: https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/59821927.html and https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html

Comment: I pip installed them. Will look at the links when I have some more time tonight!

Comment: any news on this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Raikish I got around this by learning what a virtual environment was, and setting up on of those to separate my two python versions. It seems like a best practice that was glossed over in a lot of intro books.